# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

From this AngularJS code:

```
dataProvider.CustomAssets.save({
    'product'   : product.id,
    'store'     : store.id
})
.then(function(asset){
    $scope.product.assets.key.push(
        name            : asset[0],
        additionalPrice : asset[1],
        file            : asset[2],
        attribute       : asset[3]
    );
})
.catch(function(error){
    $log.error(error);
});
```

What kinds of mistakes produce this AngularJS Syntax error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to wrap object with `{}` .

```
 $scope.product.assets.key.push(
        name            : asset[0],
        additionalPrice : asset[1],
        file            : asset[2],
        attribute       : asset[3]
    );
```

Try this

```
 $scope.product.assets.key.push({
        name            : asset[0],
        additionalPrice : asset[1],
        file            : asset[2],
        attribute       : asset[3]
    });
```